# WebRTC on Android device with API 15

Tags: android, webrtc

i have implemented a WebRTC project and now I want to load it via USB cable to an old LG smartphone which has API level 15.

But the problem is that the org.webrtc library accepts only a minSDK version of 16. So, setting minSDKVersion to 15 and using the org.webrtc library side by side in my app gradle file does not work very well.

Can somebody tell me which options I have ?

Here is how my app gradle file looks like:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.celik.abdullah.videocallapp5"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'
    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

And here is the error Android Studio gives me when I sync it:

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.28513] /home/ac3l1k/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/google-webrtc-1.0.28513.aar/67de37abe527cac122aa33b727c072c3/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.webrtc" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

How my project looks like:
I want to use two Android devices (a Samsung device with API level 24 which works very well + a LG P700 device with API level 15 which causes me this problem) as clients. My laptop runs the socket.io server.js file which acts as signalling server.

What I tried:
An emulator as a replacement for the LG device does not work. The display is not showing the video frames. I only hear the audio but not the video.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: I know that. But is there a solution for devices with API level < 16 ?

Comment: Check Webrtc doc's if they mention that the sdk support above 16 then there's no solution.

Comment: I believe that the easiest option is to upgrade the LG device to a custom ROM with a higher API. I see that KitKat (API 19) is available.